# How to send queryStringParameters with invokeApi command

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

The full path to the endpoint with the query string parameters is:

```
https://api.mydomain.com/getData?param_01=value_01&param_02=value_01
```

After importing the 'aws-api-gateway-client'

```
var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;
```

I go ahead and configure the variables:

```
let url = 'https://api.mydomain.com'
let pathTemplate = '/getData?param_01=value_01&param_02=value_01';

let method = 'GET';
let params = '';
let additionalParams = '';
let body = '';
```

```
var client = apigClientFactory.newClient({
  invokeUrl: url, 
  accessKey: 'my-accessKeyId',
  secretKey: 'my-secretAccessKey',
  sessionToken: 'my-sessionToken',
  region: 'MY_AWS_REGION'
});
```

Next invoke endpoint with:

```
client
  .invokeApi(params, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log("...res:", res);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("...err:", err);
  });
```

But it fails with the error

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details
```

Is there a way to send the queryStringParameters with `invokeApi` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let params = {};
let pathTemplate = '/getData';
let additionalParams = {
    queryParams: {
        param0: 'value0',
        param1: 'value1'
    }
};
```

[aws-api-gateway-client - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-api-gateway-client)